# How to import .vpd files into visual paradigm project

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I’m in trouble,
for an exam I made all my diagram project (class, use case, sequence and activity) in visual paradigm online.
Now I need to make a .vpp files with this diagram but… I just realized I can’t export easily diagram from vp online to vp client and the only thing I can do is export it in .vpd.

I need help, I can’t make all diagram from beginning.
how can I create a .vpp contain all this diagram?

how I can open a .vpd file?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In desktop, go to team -> select repository -> Existing registered user -> Enter username and password or login through google

Now, you'll be able to see all the projects you created online. If you didn't create one online, you can also import individual diagrams:

Team -> Import from web diagram -> select diagram -> Click on import
[See the text at bottom of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huivm.png)

Comment: The question was how to open vpd files in visual paradigm desktop version. Can that be done without connecting to the online system which I will never use.

Answer (score 1):

Some diagrams (Use Case Diagram, Class Diagram, Business Process Diagram, ArchiMate and PERT Chart) can directly import form VP Online to VP Desktop client. But for the others they are run separate between VP Online and VP Desktop. Details can be found at https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/vp-online/diagram-compatibility/